# How to make the codes different type using Django and Python

Tags: python, django

I need some help. I need to make different for for same code writing as per some condition using Django and Python. I am explaining my code and the scenario below.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        location_name = request.POST.get('lname')
        rname = request.POST.get('rname')
        seat = request.POST.get('seat')
        projector = request.POST.get('projector')
        video = request.POST.get('video')
        num=str(random.randint(100000000000,999999999999))
        doc = m.parse("roomlist.xml")
        root=doc.getElementsByTagName("roomlist")
        valeurs = doc.getElementsByTagName("roomlist")[0]
        element = doc.createElement("location")
        element.setAttribute("name"  , location_name)
        el1 = element.appendChild(doc.createElement("room"))
        el1.setAttribute("id", num)
        el2=el1.appendChild(doc.createElement("roomname"))
        el2.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(rname))
        el3=el1.appendChild(doc.createElement("noseats"))
        el3.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(seat))
        el4=el1.appendChild(doc.createElement("projectorscreen"))
        el4.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(projector))
        el5=el1.appendChild(doc.createElement("videoconf"))
        el5.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(video))
        valeurs.appendChild(element)
        doc.writexml(open("roomlist.xml","w"))
    return render(request, 'booking/bmr.html', {})
```

Here this is my form data which are storing into xml format. But I need to serch the data  as per the following condition.

```
1-Vulnerable code: Application uses SQL Query to search for the room(use sql query to search xml data). The user input (room name) is direct without any validation resulting in injection attack.
2-Incorrect solution #1: Escape special SQL characters by hand adding a `\` before any special characters
3-Incorrect solution #2: URL encode paste contents in the request before passing it to the model layer
4-Incorrect solution #3: Remove special SQL characters
5-Correct solution: Use prepared statement and pass arguments to it properly
```

My xml file is given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><roomlist>
  <location name="Bangalore">
    <room id="1uy92j908u092">
      <roomname> Aquarius </roomname>
      <noseats> 10 </noseats>
      <projectorscreen>yes</projectorscreen>
      <videoconf>yes</videoconf>
    </room>
  </location>
<location name="Bhubaneswar"><room id="131198912460"><roomname>cottage</roomname><noseats>5</noseats><projectorscreen>Yes</projectorscreen><videoconf>Yes</videoconf></room></location><location name="puri"><room id="509955554930"><roomname>room1</roomname><noseats>10</noseats><projectorscreen>No</projectorscreen><videoconf>Yes</videoconf></room></location></roomlist>
```

Here I need to modify the code as per the above condition.Please help me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @moritzg : Actually i want to search the data and uses all above condition. Let me to post my xml file .